# Textfield below submit button not working inside form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with submit button on top and textfields after submit button.

Now the problem is while submitting the form, the values inside the textfields are not getting.

What's the problem. Am attaching my code here. Please have a look.

```
<form action="write_blog_add.php" method="post" id="form1">
    <button type="submit" name="publish" id="upload">Publish</button>
    <input type="text" name="blog_title" placeholder="Blog Title Comes Here" />
    <input type="text" name="blog_descr" placeholder="Blog Description Comes Here" />
</form>
```

Is there any way to solve my issue. I am using Jquery to submit form data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upload').click(function() {
        $("#viewimage").html('');
        $("#viewimage").html('<img src="images/Preloader_2.gif" />');
        $("#form1").ajaxForm({
            target: '#viewimage'
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: “The values inside the textfields are not getting” what?

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec :- while submitting form, the text entered inside the textfield are empty or nothing displaying. I have updated my code. Please have a look.

Comment: i still don't understand what you mean/what the problem is. can you maybe explain in very simple sentences, what you do, what happens, and what part is wrong?